# Thus, firebase_core ^0.7.0 is incompatible with cloud_firestore ^0.14.0

Tags: flutter

Running pub get or pub upgrade results in the following error:

```
[battlehighland] flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in battlehighland...                  
Because no versions of firebase_core match >0.7.0 <0.8.0 and firebase_core 0.7.0 depends on firebase_core_platform_interface ^3.0.1, firebase_core ^0.7.0 requires firebase_core_platform_interface ^3.0.1.

Because cloud_firestore ^0.14.3+1 depends on firebase_core_platform_interface ^2.1.0 and cloud_firestore >=0.14.0 <=0.14.3 depends on firebase_core_platform_interface >=2.0.0 <2.1.0, cloud_firestore ^0.14.0 requires firebase_core_platform_interface >=2.0.0 <2.1.0 or ^2.1.0.

Thus, firebase_core ^0.7.0 is incompatible with cloud_firestore ^0.14.0.

So, because battlehighland depends on both cloud_firestore ^0.14.0+1 and firebase_core ^0.7.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because battlehighland depends on both cloud_firestore ^0.14.0+1 and firebase_core ^0.7.0, version solving failed.)
exit code 1
```

My pubspec.yaml:

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: ^0.16.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  eva_icons_flutter: ^2.0.1
  firebase_auth: ^0.20.0+1
  firebase_core: ^0.7.0
  firebase_storage: ^7.0.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.11.0
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.9
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+22
  page_transition: ^1.1.7+6
  provider: ^4.3.3
```

Project is created by following official guides in the last week.

Comment: same error happen with me

Comment: change `cloud_firestore: ^0.16.0` to `cloud_firestore: ^0.16.0+1`

Comment: change  firebase_core: ^0.7.0 to firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9

Comment: @ZohaibTariq working thanks...